# Prevent blocked Apps from bypassing Firewall through VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, firewall, openvpn, windows-firewall

I have a big problem where before using a VPN I had Windows Firewall Control app prevent certain apps from accessing the internet.
It used the windows firewall and blocked all access that I didn't grant.

This setup was working well for me as I was able to block telemetry apps and other nuisances that kept using my bandwidth.

The problem I am facing now started when I started using VyperVPN (and generally most VPNs NordVPN,AirVPN etc).

Now the traffic almost completely bypasses Windows Firewall and it is as if I had no firewall at all.

I say almost completely because I still get some popups from the firewall, but rarely.

When I used to install a software which had addons of bloat bundled with it, it was no big deal at all. The firewall by default pops up and asks you for permission and as long as you haven't granted it yet it will stay completely offline.

Now installing those softwares is a pain in the butt as you might imagine.

I am currently using VyprVPN using Chameleon protocol to bypass my ISP's block on VPNs.
Before VyperVPN i used to use OpenVPN on SSL as I couldn't connect to VPN otherwise.

Is there a method or a certain firewall that I can with which I can block apps regardless if I am using VPN or not?

Thanks

**Edit:**

```
Route without VPN
```

[image]

```
Route /w VPN connected
```

[image]